# when I run "rm -rf node_modules in laravel terminal I am getting error

Tags: laravel

here it is the error
when I run rm -rf node_modules I am getting this

Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:4

- rm -rf node_modules
- 

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write
`rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: I am so sorry I edited the question....check it again

Answer (score 0):

Powershell rm equalant for linux rm -rf is

Syntax
`rm <path to delete> -r -fo`

-r recursively
-fo force

For your case

`rm node_modules -r -fo`

Comment: I am so sorry I edited the question....check it again

Comment: Ooops.Due you are using powershell you have to use

rm <path to delete> -r -fo

Comment: Always glad to help :) If my answer did indeed solve your problem, I'd be delighted if you could accept my answer by clicking that check mark on the left...